# How to name output file with respect to input file?

Tags: csv, batch-file, filenames

I have about 100 input files which, after processing, generate more than 2000 output files. I would like to name the output files based on the names of the input file.

Here is the command I run:

```
Start cmd /k "G:Path\eachGeo.bat G:\Path\InputGeo\*.csv"
```

The input files are read via `cmd` by executing the `.bat` file. Output is stored at a different path:

```
outputfilename = 'Path\outputGeo\\' + Time.now.to_i.to_s + 
                 '_' + eachTag[45..54] + '_output.csv'
```

In the code above I am using `Time.now.to_i.to_s` to name the output files based on the current system time.

I would like to change this to be the name of the input file.

Comment: You'll have a much easier time using `/` in pathnames since it doesn't require a ton of escaping. Also try and keep variable names all `lower_case`, so that should be `each_tag` intstead.

Comment: You can also do `name = "path/%d_%s_output.csv" % [ Time.now.to_i, each_tag[45..54] ]` which tends to be significantly less messy. That's just `sprintf` notation using the `%` shorthand method.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that ..

Comment: But I want to eliminate the `Time.now.to_i` and put the input file name instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you'd tackle it like this where you're using things like [`File.basename`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/File.html#method-c-basename) to extract the relevant part of the original file path:

```
Dir.glob("path/*.csv") do |path|
  CSV.open(path) do |csv_in|
    # ...

    out_path = "output_path/%s_%s.csv" % [
       File.basename(path, ".csv"),
       each_tag[45..54]
    ]

    CSV.open(out_path, "w") do |csv_out|
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

This is a really simple example. I'd avoid putting your output files in the same directory as the input ones so you don't mistakenly read them in again when you run the program a second time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but You should please look into the edit in the question I made just now. The inputs are in different folder and the outputs also in different. I read them via execution in cmd - bat file.

Comment: That's practically a whole new question. What do the batch files have to do with this?

Comment: The entire program is about scraping web with a query search. The bat read the input geo coordinates from input file and passed to query and the searched outputs are stored in another csv. The whole process works just fine. But now the search geo locations are more than 100 and naming the output files is becoming a challenge. So I am trying to name the outputs with respect to input filenames.

Comment: It would be better to do the scraping inside your Ruby application if that's not too complicated a process. In any case, if you have input files of arbitrary `*.csv` names, this template here should work.

Comment: I am very new to ruby programming, so changing the structure of the program might not be as easy for me at present. I am little better with python but I am not sure if the same logic can work with python.

Comment: Ruby and Python have a fair bit in common, even though they often take different approaches to solving problems. All this does is spin over a given input directory, then construct output filenames based on each input name. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you so much but this isnt working for me, gives me error .. And I cannot put the entire code here :(

Comment: Just try and build up to a bigger solution based on little bits that actually work. The incremental approch is the only way to tackle big problems.

Comment: Sure I will try with approach .. But just so confused here :(

Comment: Make little test scripts that do something right, and out of those assemble a more robust solution. Most of my scripts start with loops and a bunch of `puts` statements to make sure I'm getting the right values in the right order. From there you add the actual code.

Comment: Sure I will .. Thanks a bunch :)